# I can't find function SUM

Tags: php, sum

- I am PHP-developer, a beginer. And I use Object-oriented programming "MysqliDb.php". (https://github.com/joshcam/PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class/blob/master/MysqliDb.php)

Now I can't find function SUM.

I need `SUM all column 'price' from table 'models' WHERE 'model_id' == $model_id.`

```
$db->where('model_id', $model_id);
$summa = $db-> ???? ('models','price');
```

- I wrote letters to the authors of the file, but they have not responded.
- Can anybody help me?! Does anyone use this file?
- With best wishes Aibek.

Comment: you can write like $db->select("sum(price)"); right ?

Answer (score 0):

Use following query:

SELECT SUM(PRICE) AS total_price FROM table 'models' WHERE 'model_id' == $model_id.

Comment: Right answer:

`$db->where('model_id', $model_id);
$summa = $db->getValue('models', 'sum(price)');
echo 'total price: ' . $summa;`

Answer (score 0):

i think u want to do like

```
   $db->select(sum("'price') as totalnum")
    ->from("your table") 
    ->where("yourtable.model_id == $model_id")
```